# Where does Attunity's CDC services write error data?

Tags: sql-server, oracle-11g-r2, change-data-capture

We use Attunity's CDC services to move data from Oracle to SQL Server.

Using the Oracle CDC Designer snap-in tool, I can see the current status of the service and an error message if a problem has occurred.  I can click 'Collect Diagnostics' in the tool to gather messages for a date range and write to a file.

I want to find out where the diagnostic information is stored so I can read it directly through powershell from a monitoring server.

I have looked through the event logs and I can see some status messages but the diagnostic report has much more data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the data I was looking for.  In each target database there are a series of system tables within the schema cdc.  The error messages I wanted are in the cdc.xdbcdc_trace table.

```
select * from MyTarget_CT.cdc.xdbcdc_trace
```

There is a similar table in the MSXDBCDC database, but it is currently empty on my system.

There is also information regarding the connection status to Oracle from SQL Server in a file located, most of which I believe is also found in the trace table mentioned above.

```
C:\Users\CTServiceName\AppData\Local\Temp\oradiag_XXX\diag\clients\user_XXX\host_XXX\alert\log.xml
```